# Jenkins Git plugin trying to build old revision during release build

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to release a Maven project using the `maven-release-plugin`. The Jenkins Git plugin doesn't seem to be checking out the repo correctly.

Below is my Jenkins Job configuration

```
Repository URL : git@githubenterprise:/user/repo.git

Branches to build: */master

Repository browser: Auto

Additional Behaviours:

  Checkout to specific local branch : master
```

Git Build data for the failed release shows

```
Revision: 267**
refs/remotes/origin/origin/master
Built Branches

refs/remotes/origin/master: Build #4 of Revision 755** 
(refs/remotes/origin/master)
refs/remotes/origin/origin/master: Build #10 of Revision 267*** 
(refs/remotes/origin/origin/master)
```

The job console shows

```
Multiple candidate revisions
Scheduling another build to catch up with MyJenkinsBuildJob
Checking out Revision 267** (refs/remotes/origin/origin/master)
```

755** is the latest commit on the repository, bu the Git Plugin is checking out 267** revision. So the build fails when the `maven-release-plugin` tries to push back the release prepared release from an old commit.

```
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
To ssh://git@githubenterprise:/user/repo.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@githubenterprise:/user/repo.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.
```

How to make the Jenkins Git Plugin checkout only the latest revision(755* in my case) instead of trying to build multiple checkouts(not sure why it does that)

Comment: have also the problem. In my case I want to use a non-unique branch spec so it uses the local branch but it should update it after the fetch. Looks like it is only fetching remote branches but not integrate them to the local heads?!

Answer (score 6):

this was due to the fact that someone had pushed a branch with name "origin/master" which matched with the `Branches to build: */master` configuration which I had provided.So the Git plugin was trying to checkout both these matching branches ("*master*" and "*origin/master*") and build them

Removing the wildcard and setting the branch specifier to `remotes/origin/master` solved the problem.

Comment: I just encountered this - I was trying to build refs/heads/feature_branch but one of my colleagues had at some point accidentally pushed their local `feature_branch` to `FEATURE_BRANCH` on `origin`, and Jenkins was picking the head of that `FEATURE_BRANCH` (which hadn't been updated since) rather than `feature_branch`. I removed the errant branch and all is now well.

Comment: For us, we were not using wildcard, so clearing the workspace directory solved the issue.